# How can I get data from different pages with javascripts buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, web, jsoup

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <ul>
              <li class="active">
          <a class="page" data-page="1" href="javascript:void(0)">
            1          </a>
        </li>
              <li >
          <a class="page" data-page="2" href="javascript:void(0)">
            2          </a>
        </li>
              <li >
          <a class="page" data-page="3" href="javascript:void(0)">
            3          </a>
        </li>
              <li >
          <a class="page" data-page="4" href="javascript:void(0)">
            4          </a>
        </li>
              <li >
          <a class="page" data-page="5" href="javascript:void(0)">
            5          </a>
        </li>
              <li >
          <a class="page" data-page="6" href="javascript:void(0)">
            6          </a>
        </li>
              <li >
          <a class="page" data-page="7" href="javascript:void(0)">
            7          </a>
        </li>
              <li >
          <a class="page" data-page="8" href="javascript:void(0)">
            8          </a>
        </li>
              <li class="threeDots">
          <a class="page" data-page="..." href="javascript:void(0)">
            ...          </a>
        </li>
              <li >
          <a class="page" data-page="20" href="javascript:void(0)">
            20          </a>
        </li>
          </ul>
  </div>
```

When I click in this buttons I go to something like this www.example.com/something?page=X (x = number of the button)
I use this:

```html
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.example.com/something?page=5").get();
```

But I get always the first page HTML.
How I can "click" or extract information about this pages? I don't know so much about PHP but I think this page use it to change pages.

Edit:
I'm not using javascript. I'm using a java project that extract information from page using html.

Comment: Why the `Java` tag?

Comment: it is more suitable for javascript tag.

Comment: `PHP` tag is not necessary either

Comment: sorry. Its my first question.

Comment: Im not using javascript. Im using a java project that extract information from page using html.

Comment: I cont understand your question please tell us what is your expected output.

Comment: A loop that gets the updated html of each page. Only need a method in java that post and/or get the result of this buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to dynamically set the page URL argument. If you use jQuery you should be able to have a click event like this:

`Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.example.com/something?page=" + $(this).data('page')).get();`

Comment: Im not using javascript. Im using a java project that extract information from page using html.

Answer (score 0):

Only a single digit gets changed for every link, you can use for loop with a variable denoting your page number as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.example.com/something?page=" + i).get();
              /* Your code for each page*/
        }
```

Comment: i did it, but i only get Document about www.example.com/something

Comment: Do you get different pages for `www.example.com/something?page=2` and `www.example.com/something?page=4` when you paste the URL directly in the address bar in the browser?

Comment: Not diferent pages. Diferents products. Like this page: https://www.promofarma.com/salud. When i try to get html from https://www.promofarma.com/salud?=3 i get the products from https://www.promofarma.com/salud but not the products of https://www.promofarma.com/salud?=3.

Comment: I saw, it does moves to next pages, the products list is changed

Comment: how does it work? how can i get the changed products list?